# Picking pairs of two different kinds out of a jar

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have been solving this problem for my chemistry class that involves combinatorics. The problem can be simplified to this combinatorics problem:
We have $n$ things labeled $A$ and $n$ things labeled $B$ in a jar. What is the respective probability that we get $AA$, $AB$, and $BB$ without replacement? Any help works! Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your own attempt and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: I have nothing to begin with so any start would be helpful

Comment: You previously posted a question about finding the probability of drawing two pairs in a five-card hand.  Here, you are drawing two objects from $2n$ objects, $n$ of each type.  Try a similar approach.  I will be happy to check your work.

Comment: I tried that already but it did not work. I do not understand why that does not work

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried, even if it did not work.

Comment: Just curious - what Chemistry problem reduces to this one?

Answer (score 0):

For $p(AA)$ or $p(BB)$ we retrieve an object, so the next time there's going to be 1 less of such objects ($n-1$) and 1 less object overall in the jar $(2n-1)$:
$$
p(AA) = p(BB) = \frac{n}{2n} \times \frac{n-1}{2n-1} = \frac{n^2 - n}{4n^2-2n} 
$$
And in case of $p(AB)$, after we drew for the 1st time we're left with 1 less object overall $(2n-1)$, and the number of objects of *different* kind stays the same $(n)$:
$$
p(AB) = 2\frac{n}{2n} \times \frac{n}{2n-1} = 2\frac{n^2}{4n^2 - 2n} \\
$$

Notice the factor of $2$ which is due to the fact that we need to add the probabilities of $AB$ and $BA$.